# ASM algorithm decoding

Tags: algorithm, assembly, 64-bit

I am trying to understand this problem that is in ASM. Here is the code:

```
45 33 C9                    xor r9d, r9d 
C7 44 24 18 50 72 69 6D     mov [rsp+arg_10], 6D697250h 
66 C7 44 24 1C 65 53        mov [rsp+arg_14], 5365h 
C6 44 24 1E 6F              mov [rsp+arg_16], 6Fh 
4C 63 C1                    movsxd r8, ecx 
85 C9                       test ecx, ecx 
7E 1C                       jle short locret_140001342 
41 8B C9                    mov ecx, r9d 
            loc_140001329: 
48 83 F9 07                 cmp rcx, 7 
49 0F 4D C9                 cmovge rcx, r9 
48 FF C1                    inc rcx 
8A 44 0C 17                 mov al, [rsp+rcx+arg_F] 
30 02                       xor [rdx], al 
48 FF C2                    inc rdx 
49 FF C8                    dec r8 
75 E7                       jnz short loc_140001329 
            locret_140001342: 
C3                          retn
```

And here is the encoded text:

```
07 1D 1E 41 45 2A 00 25 52 0D 04 01 73 06 
24 53 49 39 0D 36 4F 35 1F 08 04 09 73 0E 
34 16 1B 08 16 20 4F 39 01 49 4A 54 3D 1B 
35 00 07 5C 53 0C 08 1E 38 11 2A 30 13 1F 
22 1B 04 08 16 3C 41 33 1D 04 4A
```

I've been studying ASM for some time now and I know what most of the commands but I still have some questions I have not found the answer to.

How do i plug the encoded text into the algorithm?
What are arg_10, arg_14, etc? I assume they are from the encoded part but I dont know exatcly.

Could someone go line by line what this algorithm does, I understand some of it but I need some clarification.

I have been using visual studio and c++ to test asm. I do know that to run an asm procedure you can declare a function like this

```
extern "C" int function(int a, int b, int c,int d, int f, int g);
```

and use it like this

```
printf("ASM Returned %d", function(92,2,3,4,5,6));
```

I am also aware that the first four parameters go into int RCX, RDX, R8, and R9 and the rest are on the stack. I don't know much about the stack so I do not know how to access them right now. I also know that the returned value is the value contained by RAX. So a something like this would add two numbers:

```
xor eax, eax
mov eax, ecx
add eax, edx
ret
```

So as  Jester suggested, I will go line by line explaining what I think the code does.

```
xor r9d, r9d                  //xor on r9d (clears the register)
mov [rsp+arg_10], 6D697250h   //moves 6D697250 to the address pointed at by rsp + arg_10
mov [rsp+arg_14], 5365h       //moves 5365 to the adress pointed at by rsp+arg_14
mov [rsp+arg_16], 6Fh         //moves 6F to the adress pointed at by rsp+arg_16
movsxd r8, ecx                //moves ecx, to r8 and sign extends it since exc is 32 bit and r8 is 64 bit
test ecx, ecx                 //tests exc and sets the labels
jle short locret_140001342    //jumps to ret if ecx is zero or less
mov ecx, r9d                  //moves the lower 32 bits or r9 into ecx

loc_140001329:                //label used by jump commands
cmp rcx, 7                    //moves 7(decimal) into rcx
cmovge rcx, r9                //don't know
inc rcx                       //increases rcx by 1
mov al, [rsp + rcx + arg_F]   //moves the the value at adress [rsp + rcx + arg_F] into al,  
                              //this is probably the key step as al is 1 byte and each character is also one byte, it is also the rax register so it holds the value to be returned
xor [rdx], al                 //xor on the value at address [rdx] and al, stores the result at the address of [rdx]
inc rdx                      //increase rdx by 1
dec r8                       //decrease r8 by 1
jnz short loc_140001329      //if r8 is not zero jump back to loc_140...
                             //this essentially is a while loop until r8 reaches 0 (assuming it starts as positive)
locret_140001342:
ret
```

I still don't know what the arg_xx are or how exactly is the encoded text plugged into this algorithm.

Comment: Since the `arg_` values are referenced against the stack pointer, I assume they're offsets for retrieving arguments from the stack.

Comment: **You** should go line by line and we will correct any mistakes. Also, switch off the "helpful" `arg_x` notation in your disassembler if you want to see raw offsets.

Comment: I'm not using a disassembler. I should of pointed out that I got this from http://www.primeso.com/interns

Comment: After a bit of staring I solved it using C. Part of the message decodes to *"Wow, you did it!"* followed by a bit more and an email address. I'm signing up right now!

Comment: That's great. Could you share how you did it? I'm still trying to figure out what the arg_10, arg_14, etc, mean.

Comment: *"How do i plug the encoded text into the algorithm?"* By setting `rdx` to the message location, and `rcx` to the message length.

Comment: @PeterCordes rather than dumb, I think that's a bit of obfuscation: the key indexing is obscured by incrementing `rcx` *before* indexing the incorrect stack offset.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the ordering of operations is a bit of an obfuscation.  `rcx` is used when it holds values in [1..8], with a displacement of `-1` from where the table was stored with `mov [mem], imm`.  My `and ecx, ~7` is still a drop-in replacement for `cmp/cmov`.  That change wouldn't affect the obfuscation.  I guess "dumb" is a bit of an overstatement though, more like a failure to optimize.  It is the obvious general-case idiom for `rcx = rcx>7? 0 : rcx`, and my suggestion only works for looping over 0..7.

Comment: @PeterCordes the key's length is only 7 not 8, so `AND` won't make its index rotate properly.

Comment: @WeatherVane: oh right, I have that mixed up (deleted my first comment, but not the 2nd to avoid totally breaking the comment thread).  For one thing, I need `and ecx, 7` to clear all **but** the low 3 bits.  And for another thing, it needs to zero when ecx is 7, not wait until the next iteration when ecx is 8.  So it needs to do `ecx %= 7`, which you can't do with an `AND`.  Maybe a multiply with a magic constant, if those work for remainders as well as division?  cmp/cmov is better than a `div`, but a predictable condition like that might be better with a `jcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding is largely correct, a few minor corrections:

### Correction 1

```
test ecx, ecx                 //tests exc and sets the labels
```

This sets the flags (not the labels).

### Correction 2

```
cmp rcx, 7                    //moves 7(decimal) into rcx
```

This compares rcx to the immediate value 7, and sets the flags accordingly.  (i.e. after this instruction a conditional instruction such as gt will only execute if rcx was greater than 7.)

### Correction 3

```
cmovge rcx, r9                //don't know
```

This conditionally (based on the flags you have just set) moves r9 into rcx.  The condition is ge, so this instruction only executes if rcx was greater than or equal to 7.  r9 contains 0, so the effect of this is to set rcx back to 0 when it reaches 7.

### Parameters

You are not given information on the parameters to the function, but it seems safe to assume that rcx is the original length of the data to be decrypted, and rdx is a pointer to the data.

Comment: `rcx` was the original length, moved to `r8` and used as loop control.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on the code.

```
    ; rdx holds the message location
    ; ecx holds the message length

    xor r9d, r9d                ; r9d = 0
    mov [rsp+arg_10], 6D697250h ; fix up the key
    mov [rsp+arg_14], 5365h 
    mov [rsp+arg_16], 6Fh       ; which is "PrimeSo"
    movsxd r8, ecx              ; length counter
    test ecx, ecx               ; test the  message length
    jle short locret_140001342  ; skip if invalid length
    mov ecx, r9d                ; reset key index to 0
loc_140001329: 
    cmp rcx, 7                  ; check indexing of key
    cmovge rcx, r9              ; reset if o/range
    inc rcx                     ; obfusacte by incrementing first
    mov al, [rsp+rcx+arg_F]     ; ... and indexing wrong offset
    xor [rdx], al               ; encrypt the message byte
    inc rdx                     ; advance message pointer
    dec r8                      ; loop count
    jnz short loc_140001329     ; next message byte
locret_140001342: 
    retn
```

I decoded the message with a C program implementing the algorithm, but that would be too easy, so I won't post it.

**Reverse engineering**

The code does not contain enough information to solve it top-down, because some registers are used without being loaded, and labels are not defined. I solved it bottom-up, by identifying the instruction that does the encryption, and working out from there.

Although the stack labels are not defined, the nomenclature is enough of a clue to show that the parts of the key are actually consecutive, and the assumption of little-endian reveals the key. This is confirmed looking at the hex byte tabulation, which shows the three values being stored at offsets' lsb of `18`, `1C` and `1E`

Comment: Instead of "fix up", I'd say "store".  It's just storing the key into space above the return address (which is the Windows x86-64 ABI's shadow space, IIRC)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, "fix up" usually means something else. I meant store the key in a way that's not immediately apparent (by encoding as three numbers). It would have been less obvious if they had used decimal!

Answer (score 1):

one thing I noticed is that the values being stored at those stack offsets are ASCII:

```
>>> '5072696d65536f'.decode('hex')
'PrimeSo'
```

as for entering the data, you could use `xxd -r -p` and read it from stdin in the program: `xxd -r -p data.hex | ./myprog`

those `arg_14` etc. offsets have to be declared somewhere in the sources. but I would guess they're hex offsets 0xf, 0x10, 0x14, 0x16.

Comment: as for entering the data, you could use xxd -r -p and read it from stdin in the program: xxd -r -p data.hex | ./myprog -- i have no idea what that means

Comment: @Raptor2277: That's Unix / DOS shell syntax for running a hex-to-binary program and piping the input into stdin of your program.  `xxd` is a fairly standard Unix program.

Comment: From the binary: `arg_10` is `0x18`.  So the `arg_x` names match up with positions above the return address (which takes 8B on x86-64).  So `[rsp+arg_10]` is `0x10` bytes from the bottom of stack-arg space.  The weird thing about that disassembly output is that the `mov [mem], imm` instructions at the start don't have an operand size.  From the binary machine code, it looks like a dword, word, and byte store, which a good asm listing would have shown as `mov byte [mem], imm`.  Looks like it's just storing a table into memory.  It's not function parameters, but shadow space (see the win64 ABI).

Comment: Ya I tried that and it was giving me an error so i had to do "mov dword ptr [rsp + 10h], 6D697250h" and so the memory looks like this 0x0000009D3EC4FCB4  cc cc cc cc 50 72 69 6d 65 53 6f 00 00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc, which equals ÌÌÌÌPrimeSo...ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ however the algorithm uses  rcx and rdx and those registers are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have figured out the algorithm and have made it work in ASM as well. You guys were right, the arg_xx were offsets. arg_10 == 0x10, arg_f == 0x0f. The data is passed in as an array with the length of it. So rcx will be the data length in this case 47, and rdx will point to the beginning of the array. Here is the function I used in c++ to call the ASM procedure.

```
extern "C" void function(int length, char* message);
```

The algorithm is pretty simple. The key phrase is "PrimeSo". All it does is do a XOR operation on each value passed in with one of the values in "PrimeSo" in increasing order, once it reaches the 'o' in "PrimeSo" it goes back to 'P'. Hence

```
cmp rcx, 7       
cmovge rcx, r9   //as Peter de Rivaz stated this will put 0 into rcx if it is greater or equal to seven
inc rcx
```

and so

```
mov al, [rsp + rcx + 0Fh]
```

will effectively become [rsp + 1 + 0fh], [rsp + 2 + 0Fh], ..., [rsp + 7 + 0Fh]. Note that "PrimeSo" was stored at [rsp + 10h] meaning that [rsp + 1 + 0Fh] points to 'P'. In each iteration of the loop, al will become one of the characters in "PrimeSo" and it will cycle through them.

```
xor [rdx], al //This will do an xor operation on [rdx](begining of our message) and al wich is 'P' in the first loop.  
              //It will then store the result in it's place.  

inc rdx       //move to next character
dec r8        //decrease counter
jnz short loc_140001329 //and start the loop again
```

With that being said lets look at the first few ones.

```
xor P, 07 == xor 50, 07 --> 57 = W  
xor r, 1D == xor 72, 1D --> 6F = o  
xor i, 1E == xor 69, 1E --> 77 = w  
xor m, 41 == xor 6D, 41 --> 2C = ,
```

For those wondering here is the C++ code:

```
#include <fstream>

extern "C" void function(int length, char* message);

int main()
{
    char message[] = { 0x07, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x41, 0x45, 0x2A, 0x00, 0x25, 0x52, 0x0D, 0x04, 0x01, 0x73, 0x06, 0x24, 0x53, 0x49, 0x39, 0x0D, 0x36, 0x4F, 0x35, 0x1F, 0x08, 0x04, 0x09, 0x73, 0x0E, 0x34, 0x16, 0x1B, 0x08, 0x16, 0x20, 0x4F, 0x39, 0x01, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x54, 0x3D, 0x1B, 0x35, 0x00, 0x07, 0x5C, 0x53, 0x0C, 0x08, 0x1E, 0x38, 0x11, 0x2A, 0x30, 0x13, 0x1F, 0x22, 0x1B, 0x04, 0x08, 0x16, 0x3C, 0x41, 0x33, 0x1D, 0x04, 0x4A, '\0'};
    function(sizeof(message) - 1, message);
    printf("Decoded Message is:\n%s\n", message);


    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

No I did not manually insert the data into message. Also note that I added a string terminator at the end and used sizeof(message) - 1 to avoid decoding the string terminator.
Here is the ASM code, this is simply a new file called assembly.asm and has this in it.

```
.code

function proc
    xor r9d, r9d
    mov dword ptr [rsp + 18h], 6D697250h 
    mov word ptr [rsp + 1Ch], 5365h 
    mov byte ptr [rsp + 1Eh], 6Fh 
    movsxd r8, ecx
    test ecx, ecx
    jle short locret_140001342 
    mov ecx, r9d

loc_140001329:
    cmp rcx, 7
    cmovge rcx, r9
    inc rcx 
    mov al, [rsp + rcx + 17h]
    xor [rdx], al
    inc rdx
    dec r8
    jnz short loc_140001329

locret_140001342:
    ret

function endp
end
```

In visual studio, you can add a breakpoint in here and go to debug->windows->registers and debug->windows->memory-memory 1 to see the registers and the program's memory. Note that rcx will contain the count, and rdx will point to the beginning of the encoded message.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions, I couldn't of done it without you.

Comment: `arg_10` is 0x18.  The extra `8` is the size of the return address on the stack.

Comment: then what would arg_14 be? 1C?

Comment: Yup.  The names are all offset by 8B from the values.  I confirmed this by looking at the machine-code binary (since you only posted this symbolic diassembly).  `66 C7 44 24 1C` is `mov word [rsp+ 1C], imm16`.  In the machine code, it's always prefixes, opcode, addressing mode, displacement(if any), immediate(if any).  The `0x66` is the operand-size prefix that makes this a word store.  The next insn is a byte store, which has a separate opcode (`C6`) instead of a size-changing prefix, but the addressing mode is the same ([rsp + disp8] -> `44 24`), followed by a different disp8 and imm8.

Comment: Not having to work stuff like that out from manually inspecting the machine code is why it's important to have a good disassembler.  Also, your translation is wrong.  Only the first `mov` is a dword ptr.  The 2nd is a `word ptr`, the 3rd is a `byte ptr`.  It would have been more efficient to do two dword stores, including a byte of padding in the MSB of the 2nd store.  Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler outputs in valid ASM syntax for your choice of NASM/YASM/MASM/GNU as, with extra stuff in comments.  So it's great for modifying and re-assembling.